# create sticky footer in all activities android

Tags: android

Hi im trying to create an sticky footer that will show in every activity in my application, i already have the header i used windows feautre custom titlebar to achieve this so my header always shows in all my activities.

I have:

1. Activity with listview using lazyadapter to get data from xml file.
2. Activity with basic audio player.

i want to create a sticky footer si i t always shows not only when i scroll at the bottom of listview something like this:

[image]

i already have this:

**footer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
       <TextView
        android:text="Footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

and in my listview activity i used:

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer, null, false);
        list.addFooterView(footerView);
```

the footer shows but just if i scroll to the end of listview isnt sticky, which method i could use to create that sticky footer?

thanks.

edit:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />  

</LinearLayout>
```

list_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">
      <!-- android:background="@drawable/image_bg" -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/miniatura"
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/rihanna"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Title Of Song-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <!-- Artist Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/nombre"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Just gona stand there and ..." />

    <!-- Rightend Duration -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shoutcast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/nombre"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="5:45"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/shoutcast"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="5:45"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />

     <!-- Rightend Arrow -->
     <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want your footer to be in the list, because then it will only show up at the bottom of the list. Instead you want it to be another level up, inside the root element. The header and footer height should be set to wrap content so they only take up as much space as they need, and the list should be set to height=0dp weight=1 so that it takes up all the rest of the available space. Have a look at this replacement I'm providing for main.xml. You should work with your footer in the .xml layout file (if possible) and try to avoid doing it in the code.

Main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />  

    <include layout="footer"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Footer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:text="Footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i added my main.xml and list_row.xml in my post

Comment: i already have header using windows custom title feature in my .java    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  
  getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

Comment: Ok, i've removed it from my answer since it's not necessary. The rest should work.

Comment: i write it like this : pastebin.com/cpsWiPks the main.xml but now crashs doesnt not allow attribute  android:weight="1"

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'weight' in package 'android

Comment: go it bro i changed weight to android:layout_weight="1", one question how can i add some functions to that footer?

Comment: i mean for example add an image and when click to show something else

Comment: and how can i show this header in all of my activities? thanks

Comment: My bad, as you've already figured out it's supposed to be layout_weight. I changed the answer. I would recommend using an xml layout and an include tag like with the footer. Is there a reason you're using a Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: i use that for my header i dont remember but i had issues in changing the default header so i tried that and worked perfect

Comment: what u recommend me to setup some code for my footer? need to create some .java class?

Comment: Ok. Like i said I would do it the same way as the footer. For the code I would create a subclass of Activity, maybe HeaderFooterActivity, that all your activities can inherit. Then add your code to the HeaderFooterActivity.onCreate, and make sure to call super.onCreate in all of your activies onCreate method. Keeps you from duplicating functionality.

Comment: How to make the footer always visible, the LinearLayout did not work.

Answer (score 2):

In your XML wrap the rest of you views (listview, ect...) in a ScrollView

Comment: i tried but without luck i added in my post the main.xml and list_row.xml can u help me please im still getting the footer at the end of listview non sticky

Comment: are you adding the footer to the list? .. list.addFooterView(footerView);

Comment: i use this View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer, null, false);
        list.addFooterView(footerView);

Comment: im getting footer but just at the end of listview :(

Comment: i have a footer.xml as u can see in my post also a main.xml and list_row.xml